# How to achieve the following in excel formula

Tags: excel

I have one excel sheet with 6 rows. I want to match the value of B2 in entire column of E () excluding the header & when the exact match found then find the corresponding row value(which is in F) paste the value in G2. How to do it in excel formula?

Please refer the screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: @Jeeped I want to fill the cell where the value find in column "E" with any color or any kind of mark like strike out .how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in G2,

```
=index(f:f, match(b2, e:e, 0))
```

Comment: I want to fill the cell where the value find in column "E" with any color or any kind of mark like strike out .how to do it ?